# Excel formula to display texts based on value in other sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a Master sheet that contains formulas that is based on the combination of the cells in other sheets in an excel file. The Master sheet displays a string value (Available/Not Available/Blank(default state))
based on the values selected(Available/Not Available) from a drop-down in the other sheets.

Given I have sheets A-Z and a Master sheet: When for example

- the value "Available" is selected in Sheets A, B, and C, the corresponding formula
  cell in the Master sheet should display as "Available" without considering the contents of the D-Z(the default state of the cells in A-Z are blanks).
- If A&B are "Available" and Z is selected as "Not Available", then the Master should display "Partly Available".
- If say A, D and F are 'Not Available', the Master should display 'Not Available"

Currently, when I select Available in sheets A, B, and C,
the Master sheet displays Partly Available because the other sheets have not been populated. I need the formula to only consider the sheets that has been selected and ignore the ones that are still in their default(blank) state

My current formula is this and I believe its the issue why I am yet to get it right

```
=IF(AND(SheetA!E15="Available",SheetB!E11="Available",...SheetZ!E11="Available),"Available",IF(OR(SheetA!E15="Available",SheetB!E11="Available",...SheetZ!E11="Available"),"Partly Available",IF(AND(SheetA!E15=" Not Available",SheetB!E11="Not Available",...SheetZ!E11="Not Available"),"Not Available",""))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use COUNTIF function to count how many cells are fill with 'Available', 'Not Available' and based on that information build small (height=2) decision tree with IF function.
Decision tree here (pseudocode) is:

```
-if count of 'Available' > 0 ?
    -if yes then if count of 'Not Available' > 0 ?
        -if yes -> 'Partly Available'
        -if no -> 'Available'
    -if no then if count of 'Not Available' > 0 ?
        -if yes -> 'Not Available'
        -if no -> 'No Data/Null'
```

Excel formula that are equivalent to that decision tree could be something like this:

```
=IF((COUNTIF(A1:Z1,"=Available"))>0,IF((COUNTIF(A1:Z1,"=Not Available"))>0,"Partly Available","Available"),IF((COUNTIF(A1:Z1,"=Not Available"))>0,"Not Available","No Data"))
```

but remember that A1:Z1 reffers to cells that are somwhere else, in diffrent sheets (SheetA!E11:SheetB!E11:SheetC!E11: ... :SheetZ!E11)